# Unity 3D UI animation problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation

Can you help me with my c# unity3d UI problem? I need to know how to achieve the following animation:

I have a grid with multiple rows in UI, in which each cell has one item. Now assume that I delete one of these items, all items to the right of the deleted item should be moving one cell to the left as to fill the empty cell. For the items in the cells at the extreme left of the grid, I want them to disappear through the left side of their cell and re-emerge through the ride side of the extreme-right cell in the row above (in a sort of "portal" effect). How can I do this animation? And also: How can I do this animation if deleting multiple items in different rows at the same time.

I tried to bypass this problem by using duplicate items, but it did not work, and even if it did, it is not effective as it requires too much resources